# Can I open two Tkinter Windows at the same time?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.4

Is it possible to open 2 windows at the same time?

```
import tkinter as Tk
import random
import math
root = Tk.Tk()
canvas = Tk.Canvas(root)
background_image=Tk.PhotoImage(file="map.png")
canvas.pack(fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1) # Stretch canvas to root window size.
image = canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=Tk.NW, image=background_image)
root.wm_geometry("794x370")
root.title('Map')
root.mainloop()

optimized_root = Tk.Tk()
optimized_canvas = Tk.Canvas(optimized_root)
optimized_root.pack(fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)
optimized_image = second.create_image(0, 0, anchor=Tk.NW, image=background_image)
optimized_root.wm_geometry("794x370")
optimized_root.title('Optimized Map')
optimized_root.mainloop()
```

I'm drawing lines on the first map and then optimizing them to different locations on the second map. That part isn't pictured here, but I want to just open both windows simultaneously and have the random starting points going towards their closest location in the second window. Everything works if I run one at a time, but I have to comment out the other half.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have made your first window the other window needs to be a Toplevel

Check out this link to tkinters [Toplevel](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm) page.

EDIT:

I was playing around with your code to see if I could manage to get 2 windows to open and display an image. Here is what I came up with. It might not be perfect but its a start and should point you in the right direction.

I put the toplevel in as a defined function and then called it as part of the main loop.

NOTE: The `mainloop()` can only be called once.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import math

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root)
background_image=PhotoImage(file="map.png")
canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1) # Stretch canvas to root window size.
image = canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=background_image)
root.wm_geometry("794x370")
root.title('Map')

def toplevel():
    top = Toplevel()
    top.title('Optimized Map')
    top.wm_geometry("794x370")
    optimized_canvas = Canvas(top)
    optimized_canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    optimized_image = optimized_canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=background_image)

toplevel()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You might want to mention that you must also call `mainloop` exactly once.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I was playing with the code trying to get it to work on my end before updated my answer.