# Opening a Tkinter Window and a Pyglet Window at the same time

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a stripped down piece of code below that first opens an empty tkinter window, and then, once that tkinter window is closed it will open a pyglet window.

How can I force these two windows to open at the same time?

There is a similar question at the link below about opening two tkinter windows at the same time using toplevel() but I do not believe it applies to my problem.

- [Python: Can I open two Tkinter Windows at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43552320/python-can-i-open-two-tkinter-windows-at-the-same-time/43552391)

Thanks in advance

```
import pyglet
from tkinter import *

# Open's a tkinter window
root = Tk()
mainloop()

# Open's a Pyglet Window only after the tkinter window as been closed
class Window(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


window = Window()
pyglet.app.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry guys. I clearly hadn't finished reading all the options. Revised code below seems to do the trick using Threading:

```
import pyglet
from tkinter import *
import threading
from threading import Thread


def run1():
    root = Tk()
    mainloop()


def run2():
    class Window(pyglet.window.Window):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    window = Window()
    pyglet.app.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target=run1).start()
    Thread(target=run2).start()
```